# JBoss 5 truncates trailing = of a base64 cookie string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, base64, jboss5.x

After upgrading from JBoss 4 to JBoss 5, I've noticed the most annoying regression. It truncates the trailing equal sign ('=') of a base64 cookie value.

It took me so much time to understand that the problem wasn't my code but JBoss', I googled it and find out it's a known [issue](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-7372) .

The suggested work around is to calculate the string length and pad it with trailing equal signs (to a length that is multiplicity of 4).

As our application can run on several application servers (e.g. WebLogic, WebSpehere) I am very reluctant to add this piece of code specific for this version of JBoss.

Did anybody encounter this? Can you suggest a smarter workaround?

*edit:* thanks to @skaffman I understood my problem, I shouldn't have used base64 for cookie string in the first place. There is a variant on base 64 called [base64 url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) that should be used for such strings (cookies, urls...). The library Apache codec for example supports this variant in its base 64 implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have control over how your cookies are created and encoded/decoded? If so, then you could switch to an alternative encoding mechanism, one which doesn't use characters which may clash with the cookie specification.  For example, [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) includes a [Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class which can encode and decode binary data to and from a hex string. It'd be larger than the equivalent data in base64, but that may not matter.

Alternatively, you could play with the [Cookie](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) API a bit. The javadoc for [Cookie.setValue()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setValue%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> With Version 0 cookies, values should
>   not contain white space, brackets,
>   parentheses, **equals signs**, commas,
>   double quotes, slashes, question
>   marks, at signs, colons, and
>   semicolons. Empty values may not
>   behave the same way on all browsers.

So technically, base64 encoding is not compatible with version 0 cookies, which may be the default. You could try calling `setVersion(1)` on the cookie, and see if that makes a difference, although then you run the risk of browser compatibility issues.

Comment: oh I didn't know these stuff... as a matter of fact I do have control over the cookies creation so I'll examine other formats as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the bug report correctly, a correct implementation of the encoder would always produce a string which is a multiple of 4, so if you add the bug fix, it will not trigger in other app servers than JBoss. Your code will thus work on all servers. On a side note, perhaps you could implement it as a servlet filter, which will be minimally intrusive for you app.

Answer (score 1):

for jboss 5 set the below system property:

org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false

--bala